# Rstudio Server run view command while command processing

Tags: r, rstudio, rstudio-server

I'm running Rstudio server and wondering if there is a way to run a command that may take a bit of time to complete and at the same time visually explore some of my environment's dataframes.

When I click on a dataframe it issues the view() command but if R is busy, it will not let me view the dataframe until the last command finishes. Is there a way to run the view command in parallel?

Answer (score 1):

No.

The other thing you might be able is if you have the Pro version generate a parallel session